# java remove node linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list and I want to remove a node from it based on the data inside of it.

```
public Node deleteNode(String a){

    Node<String> temp = findNode(head, a);

    temp = temp.previous;

    System.out.println(temp.data);

    temp = temp.getNext().getNext();

    return temp;

}
```

This is the code I have for it, which in theory should work but it's doing nothing.

If I remove the "temp = temp.previous;" line the code works but removes the node after the one I want removed. If I run it as is then it just doesn't remove anything.

The print statement shows that I'm currently working with the node previous to the one found using the findNode(head, a) method but somehow something just gets screwed up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove a node, you need to alter the `next` and `previous` fields of neighbouring nodes.

```
if (temp.next!=null) {
    temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
}
if (temp.previous!=null) {
    temp.previous.next = temp.next;
}
```

That will link `temp`'s two neighbouring nodes to each other, bypassing `temp`.

Then it would probably make sense to remove `temp`'s references to its neighbours so it doesn't look like it is still part of the list.

```
temp.next = null;
temp.previous = null;
```

If you have separate references to the `head` and/or `tail` of your list, you need to reassign them in the case where the node you removed lay at the beginning or end of the list.